# .net mvc internationalization returns only english language using resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, internationalization, globalization, resource-files

I am using .net MVC 4 web application and using resource files i am trying to implement the internationalization for english and chinese language, but it always returns the english language eventhough i set for chinese culture.

Does any help me where i am wrong?

Below is the code i used.

I named reosource files with names Menu.resx for english and Menu.zn.resx for chinese.

```
**web.config**

i placed below line under system.web

<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto" 
uiCulture="auto" />

 **HTML:**
        <select id="drpLanguage" style="margin:15px;float:right;">
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="zh">中文</option>
            </select>

 @using Menu = cnxconnectedcare.resourcemanager.Menu.Menu;

 <span>@Menu.Dashboard</span>

 **JS:**
    $("#drpLanguage").change(function () {
    Cookies.set("lang", $(this).val());
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Base/SetUICulture?culture='+$(this).val(),
        type: 'POST',
        cahce: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    })

});

**Class:**
[HttpPost]
    public void SetUICulture(string culture)
    {

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
           new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
    }
```

Comment: Are your AJAX callback actually hit `SetUICulture` action? Your method marked with `[HttpPost]` but you're using query string for `url` AJAX property.

Comment: Yes its hitting the method and setting the culture value